# Where do I put logic to load view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my app launches:

- If I'm logged in, I want to show my main application View Controller
- If I'm not logged in, I want to show my application's login view controller

Both controllers are present on my storyboard.

What's the best practice for this? Where does this piece of logic go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement didFinishLaunching method this way :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];

    BOOL isLogin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"IS_LOGIN"];
    if (isLogin == YES)
    {
        rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainHomeView"];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

And set TRUE when you pressed login button

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"IS_LOGIN"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    HomeViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainHomeView"];
    AppDelegate *appDelagate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelagate.window.rootViewController = vc;
}
```

Comment: A minor improvement: save the memory of loading double view controllers by determining `IS_LOGIN` first, then load the `rootViewController`. In your code, if `isLogin` is `YES`, the `storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` is called twice.

Comment: Or you can put it in else case.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write this code in `AppDelegate.m`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function

```
    // Check if user is logged in
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"loggedIn"] == NULL || [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"loggedIn"] isEqualToString:@"false"]) {
        // show login page
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    } else {

        // show home page
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```

Here you will have to set value in `NSUserDefaults` when user is logged in. If user is not logged in show loginVC else homeVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can have it so that the login view controller is the initial view controller. And if they are logged in then in the viewWillAppear method you can segue to the other view controller.

Answer (score 0):

This logic is best for the splash viewController (basicly a screen that has a picture on the whole screen) 
in this viewController you check if logged in, if yes perform segue to main application ViewController
else, to login ViewController

Hope this helps!

Comment: No. This is a really bad practice. You wasted device memory to load a new useless splash view controller. Launch images are already doing the job, and you can implement your codes in App Delegate.